# java - reading a hashtable from a text file

Tags: java, file, hashtable

I have two files - `write.java` and `read.java`. The write.java file writes a hashtable into the text file and the function of read.java is to read that hashtable from the text file.

write.java:

```
Hashtable hash1 = new Hashtable();
hash1.put("1", "Hi!");

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("abc.txt");
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
bufferedWriter.write(hash1.toString());
bufferedWriter.close();
```

It writes peroperly into the text file. Now read.java has to read this hashtable from abc.txt and then add one more key value paid. What is the best way to achieve this?

read.java:

```
String dnstemp = "abc.txt";
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(dnstemp);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
bufferedReader.close();
```

But the `line` variable is a string...how to convert it into a hashtable to perform further operations?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Try to write it yourself then you can ask a question if you have a specific problem you encounter whilst trying to write it

Comment: Don't write the map using `toString()` -- it will be difficult to parse. If your keys and values are both Strings you should look at the Properties class. Another good option would be to serialize the map as JSON using one of the many libraries out there.

Comment: updated my question @Natecat

Comment: Use object serialization instead; so you don't have to convert from String to Hashtable and vice versa. [And here is a short documentation on how to do it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use Properties instead Hashtable. It has capability of loading and storing

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you shouldn't really be reconstructing it from its `toString()` output. Having said that, here's how you could accomplish it with Guava:

```
Map<String, String> map = Splitter.on(", ")
        .withKeyValueSeparator('=')
        .split(line.subSequence(1, line.length() - 1));

// if you specifically need a Hashtable:
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable(map);
```